# Using filter_ in dplyr where both field and value are in variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to filter a dataframe using a field which is defined in a variable, to select a value that is also in a variable. Say I have

```
df <- data.frame(V=c(6, 1, 5, 3, 2), Unhappy=c("N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N"))
fld <- "Unhappy"
sval <- "Y"
```

The value I want would be `df[df$Unhappy == "Y", ]`.

I've read the `nse` vignette to try use `filter_` but can't quite understand it. I tried

```
df %>% filter_(.dots = ~ fld == sval)
```

which returned nothing. I got what I wanted with

```
df %>% filter_(.dots = ~ Unhappy == sval)
```

but obviously that defeats the purpose of having a variable to store the field name. Any clues please? Eventually I want to use this where `fld` is a vector of field names and `sval` is a vector of filter values for each field in `fld`.

Comment: Edited the question to add sample

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try with `interp` from `lazyeval`

```
 library(lazyeval)
 library(dplyr)
 df %>%
     filter_(interp(~v==sval, v=as.name(fld)))
 #   V Unhappy
 #1 1       Y
 #2 5       Y
 #3 3       Y
```

For multiple key/value pairs, I found this to be working but I think a better way should be there.

```
  df1 %>% 
    filter_(interp(~v==sval1[1] & y ==sval1[2], 
           .values=list(v=as.name(fld1[1]), y= as.name(fld1[2]))))
 #  V Unhappy Col2
 #1 1       Y    B
 #2 5       Y    B
```

For these cases, I find the `base R` option to be easier.  For example, if we are trying to `filter` the rows based on the 'key' variables in 'fld1' with corresponding values in 'sval1', one option is using `Map`.  We subset the dataset (`df1[fld1]`) and apply the FUN (`==`) to each column of `df1[f1d1]` with corresponding value in 'sval1' and use the `&` with `Reduce` to get a logical vector that can be used to `filter` the rows of 'df1'.

```
 df1[Reduce(`&`, Map(`==`, df1[fld1],sval1)),]
 #   V Unhappy Col2
 # 2 1       Y    B
  #3 5       Y    B
```

#### data

```
df1 <- cbind(df, Col2= c("A", "B", "B", "C", "A"))
fld1 <- c(fld, 'Col2')
sval1 <- c(sval, 'B')
```

Comment: you've [answered this before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569154/use-variable-names-in-functions-of-dplyr) as follows, modified here to fit this post's names: `df %>%
     filter(get(fld, envir=as.environment(df))==sval)`. I just tried that, and it worked, too.

Comment: @ulfelder I got a comment in another post by Hadley that it is not better to use `get` .  I don't have the link though.

Answer (score 10):

Now, with `rlang` 0.4.0, it introduces a new more intuitive way for this type of use case:

```
packageVersion("rlang")
# [1] ‘0.4.0’

df <- data.frame(V=c(6, 1, 5, 3, 2), Unhappy=c("N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N"))
fld <- "Unhappy"
sval <- "Y"

df %>% filter(.data[[fld]]==sval)

#OR
filter_col_val <- function(df, fld, sval) {
  df %>% filter({{fld}}==sval)
}

filter_col_val(df, Unhappy, "Y")
```

More information can be found at https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/

**Previous Answer**

With dplyr 0.6.0 and later, this code works:

```
packageVersion("dplyr")
# [1] ‘0.7.1’

df <- data.frame(V=c(6, 1, 5, 3, 2), Unhappy=c("N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N"))
fld <- "Unhappy"
sval <- "Y"

df %>% filter(UQ(rlang::sym(fld))==sval)

#OR
df %>% filter((!!rlang::sym(fld))==sval)

#OR
fld <- quo(Unhappy)
sval <- "Y"
df %>% filter(UQ(fld)==sval)
```

More about the `dplyr` syntax available at http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html and the quosure usage in the `rlang` package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlang/index.html .

If you find it challenging mastering non-standard evaluation in dplyr 0.6+, Alex Hayes has an excellent writing-up on the topic: https://www.alexpghayes.com/blog/gentle-tidy-eval-with-examples/

**Original Answer**

With dplyr version 0.5.0 and later, it is possible to use a simpler syntax and gets closer to the syntax @Ricky originally wanted, which I also find more readable than using `lazyeval::interp`

```
df %>% filter_(.dots = paste0(fld, "=='", sval, "'"))

#  V Unhappy
#1 1       Y
#2 5       Y
#3 3       Y

#OR
df %>% filter_(.dots = glue::glue("{fld}=='{sval}'"))
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's an alternative with base `R`, which is maybe not very elegant, but it might have the benefit of being rather easily understandable:

```
df[df[colnames(df)==fld]==sval,]
#  V Unhappy
#2 1       Y
#3 5       Y
#4 3       Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from LmW; personally I prefer using a dplyr pipeline where the dots are specified before the pipeline so that it is easier to use programmatically, say in a loop of filters.

```
dots <-  paste0(fld," == '",sval,"'")
df   %>% filter_(.dots = dots)
```

LmW's example is correct but the values are *hardcoded*.

Comment: I don't see what is hardcoded in `df %>% filter_(.dots = paste0(fld, "=='", sval, "'"))` compared with your code. They are programmiccally equivalent from what I can see.

Comment: Yeah sorry that wasn't meant to sound so *harsh*.  Merely that in your CORRECT response the filter is baked directly into the pipe.  By defining the dots externally it is a little easier to change those dots (say with a loop) such that the pipe can be applied over a range of data with differing filters each time.

Answer (score 0):

So I was trying to do the same thing, and it seems that now dplyr has a builtin functionality to address exactly this.

Check the last example here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html

I'm also pasting it here for simplicity:

```
# To refer to column names that are stored as strings, use the `.data` pronoun:
vars <- c("mass", "height")
cond <- c(80, 150)
starwars %>%
  filter(
    .data[[vars[[1]]]] > cond[[1]],
    .data[[vars[[2]]]] > cond[[2]]
  )
```