# dplyr NSE - how pass column names to mutate function call?

Tags: r, tidyverse, nse, dplyr

I'd like to mutate columns of a data frame using a gsub argument on columns specified in a variable, but am struggling with nonstandard evaluation.

In this toy example, I'd like to use `columns[[1]]` and `columns[[2]]` instead of `.$name_A` and `.$name_B` in my call to gsub. Can I, or do I need to rethink my approach?

```
library(tidyverse)

test_df <- tibble(name_A = 
                   c("asdf", "ghjk"),
                 name_B =
                   c("qwer", "tyui"))

columns <- c("name_A", "name_B")

test_df %>%
  mutate(new_col_A = 
           gsub(pattern = 'asdf', replacement = 'NEW_VALUE_A', x = .$name_A),
         new_col_B = 
           gsub(pattern = 'tyui', replacement = 'NEW_VALUE_B', x = .$name_B))
```

Comment: You can use `rlang::sym`.  See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45465630/2461552)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there. You can use `rlang::syms` along with `!!` to do what you need.

```
library(tidyverse)

test_df <- tibble(name_A = 
                    c("asdf", "ghjk"),
                  name_B =
                    c("qwer", "tyui"))

columns <- rlang::syms(c("name_A", "name_B"))

test_df %>%
  mutate(new_col_A = 
           gsub(pattern = 'asdf', replacement = 'NEW_VALUE_A', x = !! columns[[1]]),
         new_col_B = 
           gsub(pattern = 'tyui', replacement = 'NEW_VALUE_B', x = !! columns[[2]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but you can use regex to apply mutate to columns using `mutate_at` and `matches`:

```
library(tidyverse)

test_df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(matches('A')), 
            function(.x) gsub(pattern = 'asdf', 
                              replacement = 'NEW_VALUE_A', .x)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(matches('B')), 
            function(.x) gsub(pattern = 'tyui', 
                         replacement = 'NEW_VALUE_B', .x))
```

Hope that helps!

EDIT - you can also call by index:

```
test_df %>% 
mutate_at(vars(1), 
          function(.x) gsub(pattern = 'asdf',
                            replacement = 'NEW_VALUE_A', .x)) %>%
mutate_at(vars(2),
          function(.x) gsub(pattern = 'tyui',
                            replacement = 'NEW_VALUE_B', .x))
```