# Using variables in `dplyr` filter

Tags: r, dplyr

I have made a database with consumers and each column is a condition that they meet. I want to select a bases of only meeting each condition so I made for loop, but the filter function seems not to work and in every base I get 0 results, event thou I know I should get something:

```
database <- data.frame(ID = 1:10, Con1 = c(1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1), Con2 = c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
varibles <- names(database)[2:3]

for(i in 1:length(varibles) ){
  tmp <- database %>%  
    filter_(varibles[i] == 1) 
}
```

I read that I should use filter with "_" but it dose not work ([Use variable names in functions of `dplyr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569154/use-variable-names-in-functions-of-dplyr))

I solved the problem not using the dplyr:

```
  tmp <- database  
  tmp <- tmp[tmp[, varibles[i]] == 1, ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, we don't need a loop, use the `filter_at`.

If we need to `filter` rows having either of the 'Con' values are 1, then we use the `any_vars` to quote that a predicate expression should be applied to the variables mentioned in the `.predicate` (here we use the index.  If we need the string names, then wrap it with `vars(matches("Con"))`

```
database %>%
     filter_at(2:3, any_vars(.==1))
```

Suppose, if we need to have 1 for both the columns, use the `all_vars`

```
database %>%
     filter_at(2:3, all_vars(.==1))
```

---

For multiple datasets, initiate a `list` and store the output from each iteration inside it

```
tmp <- setNames(vector("list", length(varibles)), varibles)
for(i in seq_along(varibles)){
  tmp[[i]] <- database %>%  
              filter_at(vars(varibles[i]), all_vars(. == 1)) 
}
```

Or with `sym` from `rlang`

```
tmp <- setNames(vector("list", length(varibles)), varibles)
for(i in seq_along(varibles)){
  tmp[[i]] <- database %>%  
             filter(UQ(rlang::sym(varibles[i])) == 1) 
}

tmp
#$Con1
#  ID Con1 Con2
#1  1    1    1
#2  2    1    0
#3  4    1    0
#4  8    1    0
#5 10    1    0

#$Con2
#  ID Con1 Con2
#1  1    1    1
```

---

The above approaches were doing using `R 3.4.1` and `dplyr_0.7.2`.  As the OP mentioned some difficulties in updating the R to a new version, we tried the `get` approach using `R 3.1.3` and `dplyr_0.4.3`

```
tmp <- setNames(vector("list", length(varibles)), varibles)
for(i in seq_along(varibles)){ 
     tmp[[i]] <- database %>% 
                    filter(get(varibles[i], envir = as.environment(.))==1)
 }

tmp
#$Con1
#  ID Con1 Con2
#1  1    1    1
#2  2    1    0
#3  4    1    0
#4  8    1    0
#5 10    1    0

#$Con2
#  ID Con1 Con2
#1  1    1    1
```

Comment: No, I need to get separate datafremes for each condition as I work on them later and upload to the server

Comment: I tried using your code but it dose not work. The method for filter_at produce error: " Error in function_list[[k]](value) : could not find function "filter_at" " and it appears also when I copy your code without changes. I can not also use " filter(UQ(rlang::sym(varibles[i])) == 1) " as i have old R and package ‘rlang’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1)

Comment: @MariuszSiatka  I am using R 3.4.1.  YOu could update the R to new version

Comment: It is also why "filter_at" dose not work?
Updating R is not that easy as at work I have strict rules regrading program installation, and getting all approvals will take much time and effort

Comment: @MariuszSiatka  I tried with `3.1.3` using the linked post `filter(get(varibles[i], envir = as.environment(database))==1` works for me.   The full code is `tmp <- setNames(vector("list", length(varibles)), varibles);
for(i in seq_along(varibles)){
  tmp[[i]] <- database %>%  
              filter(get(varibles[i], envir = as.environment(database))==1) 
}`