# Referring to variables by name in a dplyr function returns object not found error

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, plyr

```r
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)
sum.na <- function(df,x){df %>% summarise(n=sum(is.na(x)))}
sum.na(flights, arr_time)
```

When I run the above code, I get the error below:

```
  **Error in eval(cols[[col]], .data, parent.frame()) : 
  object 'arr_time' not found**
```

Comment: Use : `sum.na <- function(df,x){df %>% summarise(n=sum(is.na({{x}})))}`

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use variable names in functions of dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569154/use-variable-names-in-functions-of-dplyr)

Comment: Programming with dplyr has changed a lot over time, so there are some obsolete answers there.  Try this one specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56830842

Answer (score 1):

Use curly-curly (`{{}}`) to pass column names as function argument.

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)

sum.na <- function(df,x){df %>% summarise(n=sum(is.na({{x}})))}

sum.na(flights, arr_time)
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#      n
#  <int>
#1  8713
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, Thanks for the support, but still getting same error, even using curly

Comment: @Ram Hi..as shown in my answer it works for me for the `flights` dataset in `nycflights13` package. Are you doing anything differently than in my answer?

Comment: No, Just i have copied and pasted your code.

Comment: That is strange. What is the error that you get? Can you show the code that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `ensym` with `!!`

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)
sum.na <- function(df, x) { 
                 df %>%
                   summarise(n = sum(is.na(!! ensym(x))))
   }
```

It can take both quoted as well as unquoted

```
 sum.na(flights, arr_time)
 # A tibble: 1 x 1
 #     n
 # <int>
 #1  8713

 sum.na(flights, 'arr_time')
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#      n
#  <int>
#1  8713
```

Comment: Hi Akrun, Thanks for the support.   But, when i am trying to run the code given, i am getting below error.         "Error in !ensym(x) : invalid argument type"

Comment: @Ram Please check your `packageVersion('dplyr')`.

Comment: its '1.0.3'. Do you i need to use any other version?

Comment: @Ram It should be ok.  I am using 1.0.4 on R 4.0.4