# Pass along a variable to group_by in a local R function

Tags: r

Suppose I have a function:

```
mytable <- function(x, group) {
     x %>% 
        group_by({{group}}) %>% 
        summarise(n = n())
}
```

It works by passing along a variable within the function:

```
mytable(iris, Species)
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Species        n
  <fct>      <int>
1 setosa        50
2 versicolor    50
3 virginica     50
```

However it wouldn't work if:

```
group = "Species"
mytable(iris, group = group)
Error in `group_by()`:
! Must group by variables found in `.data`.
✖ Column `group` is not found.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

or call the function by another function:

```
mytable2 <- function(x, y=0, group) {
     mytable(x = x, group = group)
}

mytable2(x = iris, group = "Species")
Error in `group_by()`:
! Must group by variables found in `.data`.
✖ Column `group` is not found.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Would someone have a solution to this issue?

Comment: some reading for you: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#data--and-env-variables

Comment: tl;dr replace it with `group_by(.data[[group]])`

Comment: Or you can call with `mytable(iris, group = .data[[group]])`. But there's a big difference between strings and symbols. Trying to mix and match leads to very messy functions that are hard to program with. More discussion here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569154/use-variable-names-in-functions-of-dplyr